# Performance problem with global variables when using parallel code

Tags: c#, performance, task-parallel-library, race-condition, parallel.foreach

I have some code, that executes many tasks simultaneously with performance problems, for this questions, I have created simplified code where the same problem occurs.

In this simplified code two tasks get executed simultaneously by using `Parallel.ForEach`. The task that gets evaluated simultaneously iterates in a long for-loop and in every iteration, it alters an integer variable. If both of those two tasks alter a local integer variable, or if one alters a local integer variable and one alters a global variable, the parallel code takes almost only half the time as the serial code does (the serial code  takes about 4.5 seconds and the parallel code takes about 2.5 seconds). But if both tasks simultaneously alter different global integer variables in each loop, or if one task alters one global variable and the other tasks accesses it, the performance in the parallel code is worse (the serial evaluation takes about 5.0 seconds and the parallel evaluation takes about 7.5 seconds). Both tasks change different variables (which even are atomar datatypes), therefore I would not expect some kind of race condition, but obviously there still is something fishy going on.

I would like to know what is going on and if the solution to this problem would be changing the algorithms (In this simple code, the algorithm is the for-loop that changes the variable) such that not that often a global variable would get altered, or if there is a trick or something I have overlooked, that can solve this problem without changing the algorithm.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Program prog = new Program();
    }

    int intField1;
    int intField2;

    public Program()
    {
        this.intField1 = 0;
        this.intField2 = 0;
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

        //Here we evaluate a task, 
        //normal serial Evaluation
        Console.WriteLine("serial evaluation");
        watch.Start();
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            this.TaskThatTakesFewSeconds(j);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed milliseconds: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        watch.Stop();

        this.intField1 = 0;
        this.intField2 = 0;

        watch = new Stopwatch();
        Console.WriteLine("parallel evaluation");
        watch.Start();
        //parallel Evaluation
        int[] loops = new int[2] { 0, 1 };
        Parallel.ForEach(loops, x =>
            this.TaskThatTakesFewSeconds(x)
        );
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed milliseconds: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        watch.Stop();
    }

    public void TaskThatTakesFewSeconds(int k
    {
        int localVariable = 0;
        if (k == 0)
        {
            for (ulong j = 0; j < 1000000000; j++)
            {
                //leave one of the next two lines commented
                //localVariable++;
                this.intField1++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (ulong j = 0; j < 1000000000; j++)
            {
                //leave one of the next two lines commented
                //localVariable++;
                this.intField2++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's anyway a race condition to `++` a global variable from two threads. In your real code, are either of the two variables declared `volatile` or do you use `Interlocked`?

Comment: Your parallelized code doesn't work properly, as you're accessing shared state in an unsafe manner, so questions of performance are irrelevant.  Performance is only worth considering *after the code actually works*.

Comment: @Charlieface In my code application, the variables I use are mostly of the type `double` or `Vector<double>` from the Math.Net library. These are not atomic data types, therefore they cannot be declared as volatile and Interlocked cannot be used as well. But it is good to know, that a change of two different global variables can also invoke a race condition, I did not know that (although I assumed it after playing around a bit with this code).

Comment: @Servy In my actual application (which basically evaluates many relatively small linear algebra computations), all tasks change different variables. No matter how the computations look like, the serial evaluation's results always match the parallel results by 100%, only the performance is worse as I have told. How can parallelized code not work properly if each task only changes different variables? In this easy code example, the results always are aswell identical in the serial run and in the parallel run.

Comment: @lennartgro Then this isn't a representative example of your real problem.  Your question here is specifically about mutating shared state, so if your real examples aren't doing that, then that's a problem.  As for the results, the nature of race conditions mean they won't consistently and reliably break, they simply have the potential to behave in a number of different ways based on the order different operations end up actually running it.  That it works when you run it one time doesn't mean there are no race condition bugs.

Comment: @Servy My last comment was maybe a bit irritating I am sorry. What I was trying to say was that in my actual application, all tasks change different variables, that are all fields or properties of the given class, just the way it is in the given simplified code. In the simplified code, Task1 changes `this.intField1`, but never reads or changes `this.intField2` and Task2 changes `this.intField2` but never reads or changes `this.intField1`. This way Task1 won't call `this.intField2` when it is in the middle of the 
 process of getting its value changed and vice versa.

Comment: @lennartgro If your actual application is so different from this question then the answer to this question won't be useful in helping you solve your problem given that this is so different from your actual code.  *This* code is mutating shared state in an unsafe manner, and a program that doesn't have shared state would be so different that a performance analysis of this would be radically different from such a program.

Answer (score -1):

I would highly discourage you to use `StopWatch` for performance measurement.
I would encourage you to use [Benchmark.NET](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/index.html).

- It is a simple to use, yet really powerful micro benchmarking tool.

Let me show you how you should setup a testing environment.

### `ITest`

> This interface defines the public surface of each test case

```cs
public interface ITest
{
    void Execute();
}
```

### `Computation`

> This class contains the common logic

```cs
public class Computation
{
    private int intField1;
    private int intField2;
    public void TaskThatTakesFewSeconds(int k)
    {
        if (k == 0)
        {
            for (ulong j = 0; j < 1000000000; j++)
            {
                intField1++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (ulong j = 0; j < 1000000000; j++)
            {
                intField2++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### `SequentialTest`

> This class contains an implementation variant which will execute two operations sequentially

```cs
public class SequentialTest: ITest
{
    private readonly Computation _comp;
    public SequentialTest()
    {
        this._comp = new Computation();
    }
    public void Execute()
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            this._comp.TaskThatTakesFewSeconds(j);
        }
    }
}
```

### `ParallelForeachTest` and `ParallelInvokeTest`

> These classes contain different implementation variants.
> In both classes the operations will be executed concurrently

```cs
public class ParallelForeachTest: ITest
{
    private readonly Computation _comp;

    public ParallelForeachTest()
    {
        _comp = new Computation();
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        var loops = new [] { 0, 1 };
        Parallel.ForEach(loops, this._comp.TaskThatTakesFewSeconds);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class ParallelInvokeTest: ITest
{
    private readonly Computation _comp;

    public ParallelInvokeTest()
    {
        _comp = new Computation();
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        Parallel.Invoke(
            () => this._comp.TaskThatTakesFewSeconds(0), 
            () => this._comp.TaskThatTakesFewSeconds(1));
    }
}
```

### `TestCase`

> This class is responsible to setup the experiment

```cs
[HtmlExporter]
[MemoryDiagnoser]
[SimpleJob(BenchmarkDotNet.Engines.RunStrategy.ColdStart, targetCount: 5)]
public class TestCase
{
    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public void RunBaseLine() => RunExperiment<SequentialTest>();

    [Benchmark]
    public void RunParallelForEach() => RunExperiment<ParallelForeachTest>();

    [Benchmark]
    public void RunParallelInvoke() => RunExperiment<ParallelInvokeTest>();

    internal void RunExperiment<T>() where T : ITest, new()
    {
        new T().Execute();
    }
}
```

- `MemoryDiagnoser`: Benchmark will monitor memory usage as well
- `SimpleJob`: Here we define iterations

  - There will be iterations which won't be accounted into the final result. (*cold start*)
  - There will be 5 iterations which will be accounted during the experiment.
- `Benchmark(Baseline = true)`: The sequential variant will be used as the baseline.

  - Every other implementation will relate this (ratios)

### `Program`

> The entry point of our console application where we launch our experiment

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<TestCase>();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

---

**NOTE**: Please make sure that you run this experiment when the app is complied with **Release** mode.

The results on my laptop:

TL;DR

```
|             Method |    Mean |    Error |   StdDev | Ratio | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|------------------- |--------:|---------:|---------:|------:|------:|------:|------:|----------:|
|        RunBaseLine | 2.711 s | 0.0307 s | 0.0080 s |  1.00 |     - |     - |     - |     432 B |
| RunParallelForEach | 1.944 s | 0.1432 s | 0.0372 s |  0.72 |     - |     - |     - |    2696 B |
|  RunParallelInvoke | 1.975 s | 0.1283 s | 0.0333 s |  0.73 |     - |     - |     - |     856 B |
```

FULL

```
// Validating benchmarks:
// ***** BenchmarkRunner: Start   *****
// ***** Found 3 benchmark(s) in total *****
// ***** Building 1 exe(s) in Parallel: Start   *****
// start dotnet restore  /p:UseSharedCompilation=false /p:BuildInParallel=false /m:1 in C:\...\MySimpleBenchmark\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\7dd97576-8d82-459f-8018-efbdb1d641bc
// command took 1.35s and exited with 0
// start dotnet build -c Release  --no-restore /p:UseSharedCompilation=false /p:BuildInParallel=false /m:1 in C:\...\MySimpleBenchmark\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\7dd97576-8d82-459f-8018-efbdb1d641bc
// command took 2.23s and exited with 0
// ***** Done, took 00:00:03 (3.7 sec)   *****
// Found 3 benchmarks:
//   TestCase.RunBaseLine: Job-RWBPOP(IterationCount=5, RunStrategy=ColdStart)
//   TestCase.RunParallelForEach: Job-RWBPOP(IterationCount=5, RunStrategy=ColdStart)
//   TestCase.RunParallelInvoke: Job-RWBPOP(IterationCount=5, RunStrategy=ColdStart)

// **************************
// Benchmark: TestCase.RunBaseLine: Job-RWBPOP(IterationCount=5, RunStrategy=ColdStart)
// *** Execute ***
// Launch: 1 / 1
// Execute: dotnet "7dd97576-8d82-459f-8018-efbdb1d641bc.dll" --benchmarkName "MySimpleBenchmark.TestCase.RunBaseLine" --job "IterationCount=5, RunStrategy=ColdStart" --benchmarkId 0 in C:\...\MySimpleBenchmark\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\7dd97576-8d82-459f-8018-efbdb1d641bc\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1
// BeforeAnythingElse

// Benchmark Process Environment Information:
// Runtime=.NET Core 3.1.12 (CoreCLR 4.700.21.6504, CoreFX 4.700.21.6905), X64 RyuJIT
// GC=Concurrent Workstation
// Job: Job-MCAVLE(IterationCount=5, RunStrategy=ColdStart)

// BeforeActualRun
WorkloadActual   1: 1 op, 2703012600.00 ns, 2.7030 s/op
WorkloadActual   2: 1 op, 2722115500.00 ns, 2.7221 s/op
WorkloadActual   3: 1 op, 2714919500.00 ns, 2.7149 s/op
WorkloadActual   4: 1 op, 2704378800.00 ns, 2.7044 s/op
WorkloadActual   5: 1 op, 2708101600.00 ns, 2.7081 s/op

// AfterActualRun
WorkloadResult   1: 1 op, 2703012600.00 ns, 2.7030 s/op
WorkloadResult   2: 1 op, 2722115500.00 ns, 2.7221 s/op
WorkloadResult   3: 1 op, 2714919500.00 ns, 2.7149 s/op
WorkloadResult   4: 1 op, 2704378800.00 ns, 2.7044 s/op
WorkloadResult   5: 1 op, 2708101600.00 ns, 2.7081 s/op
GC:  0 0 0 432 1
Threading:  2 0 1

// AfterAll
// Benchmark Process 30236 has exited with code 0

Mean = 2.711 s, StdErr = 0.004 s (0.13%), N = 5, StdDev = 0.008 s
Min = 2.703 s, Q1 = 2.704 s, Median = 2.708 s, Q3 = 2.715 s, Max = 2.722 s
IQR = 0.011 s, LowerFence = 2.689 s, UpperFence = 2.731 s
ConfidenceInterval = [2.680 s; 2.741 s] (CI 99.9%), Margin = 0.031 s (1.13% of Mean)
Skewness = 0.39, Kurtosis = 1.15, MValue = 2

// **************************
// Benchmark: TestCase.RunParallelForEach: Job-RWBPOP(IterationCount=5, RunStrategy=ColdStart)
// *** Execute ***
// Launch: 1 / 1
// Execute: dotnet "7dd97576-8d82-459f-8018-efbdb1d641bc.dll" --benchmarkName "MySimpleBenchmark.TestCase.RunParallelForEach" --job "IterationCount=5, RunStrategy=ColdStart" --benchmarkId 1 in C:\...\MySimpleBenchmark\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\7dd97576-8d82-459f-8018-efbdb1d641bc\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1
// BeforeAnythingElse

// Benchmark Process Environment Information:
// Runtime=.NET Core 3.1.12 (CoreCLR 4.700.21.6504, CoreFX 4.700.21.6905), X64 RyuJIT
// GC=Concurrent Workstation
// Job: Job-OWEIXV(IterationCount=5, RunStrategy=ColdStart)

// BeforeActualRun
WorkloadActual   1: 1 op, 1885435300.00 ns, 1.8854 s/op
WorkloadActual   2: 1 op, 1951180900.00 ns, 1.9512 s/op
WorkloadActual   3: 1 op, 1989053900.00 ns, 1.9891 s/op
WorkloadActual   4: 1 op, 1944026900.00 ns, 1.9440 s/op
WorkloadActual   5: 1 op, 1948992000.00 ns, 1.9490 s/op

// AfterActualRun
WorkloadResult   1: 1 op, 1885435300.00 ns, 1.8854 s/op
WorkloadResult   2: 1 op, 1951180900.00 ns, 1.9512 s/op
WorkloadResult   3: 1 op, 1989053900.00 ns, 1.9891 s/op
WorkloadResult   4: 1 op, 1944026900.00 ns, 1.9440 s/op
WorkloadResult   5: 1 op, 1948992000.00 ns, 1.9490 s/op
GC:  0 0 0 2696 1
Threading:  6 0 1

// AfterAll
// Benchmark Process 21660 has exited with code 0

Mean = 1.944 s, StdErr = 0.017 s (0.86%), N = 5, StdDev = 0.037 s
Min = 1.885 s, Q1 = 1.944 s, Median = 1.949 s, Q3 = 1.951 s, Max = 1.989 s
IQR = 0.007 s, LowerFence = 1.933 s, UpperFence = 1.962 s
ConfidenceInterval = [1.800 s; 2.087 s] (CI 99.9%), Margin = 0.143 s (7.37% of Mean)
Skewness = -0.41, Kurtosis = 1.65, MValue = 2

// **************************
// Benchmark: TestCase.RunParallelInvoke: Job-RWBPOP(IterationCount=5, RunStrategy=ColdStart)
// *** Execute ***
// Launch: 1 / 1
// Execute: dotnet "7dd97576-8d82-459f-8018-efbdb1d641bc.dll" --benchmarkName "MySimpleBenchmark.TestCase.RunParallelInvoke" --job "IterationCount=5, RunStrategy=ColdStart" --benchmarkId 2 in C:\...\MySimpleBenchmark\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\7dd97576-8d82-459f-8018-efbdb1d641bc\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1
// BeforeAnythingElse

// Benchmark Process Environment Information:
// Runtime=.NET Core 3.1.12 (CoreCLR 4.700.21.6504, CoreFX 4.700.21.6905), X64 RyuJIT
// GC=Concurrent Workstation
// Job: Job-XWLZBM(IterationCount=5, RunStrategy=ColdStart)

// BeforeActualRun
WorkloadActual   1: 1 op, 1976197800.00 ns, 1.9762 s/op
WorkloadActual   2: 1 op, 1972453200.00 ns, 1.9725 s/op
WorkloadActual   3: 1 op, 1967741600.00 ns, 1.9677 s/op
WorkloadActual   4: 1 op, 2026004200.00 ns, 2.0260 s/op
WorkloadActual   5: 1 op, 1932835200.00 ns, 1.9328 s/op

// AfterActualRun
WorkloadResult   1: 1 op, 1976197800.00 ns, 1.9762 s/op
WorkloadResult   2: 1 op, 1972453200.00 ns, 1.9725 s/op
WorkloadResult   3: 1 op, 1967741600.00 ns, 1.9677 s/op
WorkloadResult   4: 1 op, 2026004200.00 ns, 2.0260 s/op
WorkloadResult   5: 1 op, 1932835200.00 ns, 1.9328 s/op
GC:  0 0 0 856 1
Threading:  3 0 1

// AfterAll
// Benchmark Process 11348 has exited with code 0

Mean = 1.975 s, StdErr = 0.015 s (0.75%), N = 5, StdDev = 0.033 s
Min = 1.933 s, Q1 = 1.968 s, Median = 1.972 s, Q3 = 1.976 s, Max = 2.026 s
IQR = 0.008 s, LowerFence = 1.955 s, UpperFence = 1.989 s
ConfidenceInterval = [1.847 s; 2.103 s] (CI 99.9%), Margin = 0.128 s (6.50% of Mean)
Skewness = 0.31, Kurtosis = 1.61, MValue = 2

// ***** BenchmarkRunner: Finish  *****

// * Export *
  BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts\results\MySimpleBenchmark.TestCase-report.csv
  BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts\results\MySimpleBenchmark.TestCase-report-github.md
  BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts\results\MySimpleBenchmark.TestCase-report.html

// * Detailed results *
TestCase.RunBaseLine: Job-RWBPOP(IterationCount=5, RunStrategy=ColdStart)
Runtime = .NET Core 3.1.12 (CoreCLR 4.700.21.6504, CoreFX 4.700.21.6905), X64 RyuJIT; GC = Concurrent Workstation
Mean = 2.711 s, StdErr = 0.004 s (0.13%), N = 5, StdDev = 0.008 s
Min = 2.703 s, Q1 = 2.704 s, Median = 2.708 s, Q3 = 2.715 s, Max = 2.722 s
IQR = 0.011 s, LowerFence = 2.689 s, UpperFence = 2.731 s
ConfidenceInterval = [2.680 s; 2.741 s] (CI 99.9%), Margin = 0.031 s (1.13% of Mean)
Skewness = 0.39, Kurtosis = 1.15, MValue = 2
-------------------- Histogram --------------------
[2.697 s ; 2.728 s) | @@@@@
---------------------------------------------------

TestCase.RunParallelForEach: Job-RWBPOP(IterationCount=5, RunStrategy=ColdStart)
Runtime = .NET Core 3.1.12 (CoreCLR 4.700.21.6504, CoreFX 4.700.21.6905), X64 RyuJIT; GC = Concurrent Workstation
Mean = 1.944 s, StdErr = 0.017 s (0.86%), N = 5, StdDev = 0.037 s
Min = 1.885 s, Q1 = 1.944 s, Median = 1.949 s, Q3 = 1.951 s, Max = 1.989 s
IQR = 0.007 s, LowerFence = 1.933 s, UpperFence = 1.962 s
ConfidenceInterval = [1.800 s; 2.087 s] (CI 99.9%), Margin = 0.143 s (7.37% of Mean)
Skewness = -0.41, Kurtosis = 1.65, MValue = 2
-------------------- Histogram --------------------
[1.857 s ; 1.914 s) | @
[1.914 s ; 1.995 s) | @@@@
---------------------------------------------------

TestCase.RunParallelInvoke: Job-RWBPOP(IterationCount=5, RunStrategy=ColdStart)
Runtime = .NET Core 3.1.12 (CoreCLR 4.700.21.6504, CoreFX 4.700.21.6905), X64 RyuJIT; GC = Concurrent Workstation
Mean = 1.975 s, StdErr = 0.015 s (0.75%), N = 5, StdDev = 0.033 s
Min = 1.933 s, Q1 = 1.968 s, Median = 1.972 s, Q3 = 1.976 s, Max = 2.026 s
IQR = 0.008 s, LowerFence = 1.955 s, UpperFence = 1.989 s
ConfidenceInterval = [1.847 s; 2.103 s] (CI 99.9%), Margin = 0.128 s (6.50% of Mean)
Skewness = 0.31, Kurtosis = 1.61, MValue = 2
-------------------- Histogram --------------------
[1.929 s ; 2.000 s) | @@@@
[2.000 s ; 2.052 s) | @
---------------------------------------------------

// * Summary *

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.1, OS=Windows 10.0.18363.1379 (1909/November2018Update/19H2)
Intel Core i7-8665U CPU 1.90GHz (Coffee Lake), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=5.0.103
  [Host]     : .NET Core 3.1.12 (CoreCLR 4.700.21.6504, CoreFX 4.700.21.6905), X64 RyuJIT
  Job-RWBPOP : .NET Core 3.1.12 (CoreCLR 4.700.21.6504, CoreFX 4.700.21.6905), X64 RyuJIT

IterationCount=5  RunStrategy=ColdStart

|             Method |    Mean |    Error |   StdDev | Ratio | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|------------------- |--------:|---------:|---------:|------:|------:|------:|------:|----------:|
|        RunBaseLine | 2.711 s | 0.0307 s | 0.0080 s |  1.00 |     - |     - |     - |     432 B |
| RunParallelForEach | 1.944 s | 0.1432 s | 0.0372 s |  0.72 |     - |     - |     - |    2696 B |
|  RunParallelInvoke | 1.975 s | 0.1283 s | 0.0333 s |  0.73 |     - |     - |     - |     856 B |

// * Hints *
Outliers
  TestCase.RunParallelForEach: IterationCount=5, RunStrategy=ColdStart -> 2 outliers were detected (1.89 s, 1.99 s)
  TestCase.RunParallelInvoke: IterationCount=5, RunStrategy=ColdStart  -> 2 outliers were detected (1.93 s, 2.03 s)

// * Legends *
  Mean      : Arithmetic mean of all measurements
  Error     : Half of 99.9% confidence interval
  StdDev    : Standard deviation of all measurements
  Ratio     : Mean of the ratio distribution ([Current]/[Baseline])
  Gen 0     : GC Generation 0 collects per 1000 operations
  Gen 1     : GC Generation 1 collects per 1000 operations
  Gen 2     : GC Generation 2 collects per 1000 operations
  Allocated : Allocated memory per single operation (managed only, inclusive, 1KB = 1024B)
  1 s       : 1 Second (1 sec)

// * Diagnostic Output - MemoryDiagnoser *


// ***** BenchmarkRunner: End *****
// ** Remained 0 benchmark(s) to run **
Run time: 00:00:40 (40.77 sec), executed benchmarks: 3

Global total time: 00:00:44 (44.48 sec), executed benchmarks: 3
// * Artifacts cleanup *
```

Comment: Nahh, for this case a `Stopwatch` is absolutely sufficient. You don't need the Benchmark.NET when the observed difference in performance is one order of magnitude or more. Using Benchmark.NET in this case is like using surgical tools for nailing nails on the wall.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The OP has posted a Minimal, Reproducible Example where (s)he has utilized the `StopWatch` for performance measurement. The technique what I have presented is applicable for more complex experiments as well. You can gain better insight about the performance gain or loss with this approach in my opinion than relying on `StopWatch`.

Comment: You can gain better insights by either making more observations, or by making more accurate observations. The Benchmark.NET hinders the first approach by making each observation painfully slow and tedious. Having to wait for 10 minutes in order to take ONE, extremely accurate measurement, rotating your fingers while the Benchmark.NET doing its calculations, is not everyone's cup of tee. And in this specific case it's clearly not worth it IMHO.